# Sitecore NullReferenceException on GetBrowserClassString

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sitecore, nullreferenceexception

It was a beautiful day, and I came into work and Sitecore randomly gives me this:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.UIUtil.GetBrowserClassString() +491
   Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.AddBrowserAttributes() +134
   Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +434
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +112
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4296
```

Not only was this an interruption to said day, it was altogether out of nowhere.  It does not appear that  I or any on my team have made any affecting changes, and it's been working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the error on all developer machines or just yours?

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: I have only seen this behavior when I had a wrong version of sitecore.nexus.dll in my bin dir

Answer (score 3):

We had this issue for a MultiSite Sitecore instance using Sitecore 6.5. The issue was that, as @WeekendWarrior alluded to, the `Capabitilities` Type was `null`. I found the solution on the [Sitecore forum](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=50777); however, I thought it'd be useful duplicate the simple, quick-fix part of the posted answer here because you need a Sitecore account to access the forum:

In your default site Content Editor, locate `/sitecore/layout/Devices/Default` and in the field `Capabilities Type - Type, Assembly` enter:

> Sitecore.Web.Configuration.InternetExplorerCapabilities,
>   Sitecore.Kernel

Save, then publish that item.

Answer (score 1):

Digging into GetBrowserClassString() with reflector (Sitecore.Kernel.dll), the only possible LOC that could trigger the null reference errors is:

```
Client.Device.Capabilities.Browser.MajorVersion // in the Sitecore namespace
```

Did you change your user agent string with a plugin? this might trip up this line of code. Regardless, I recommend that you put this line of code in your solution (or another test sitecore solution, debug it and see what part of it is null.